# how to loop through json element tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

im new to json. i done my study about json a little while ago but i still have very little knowledge on how to control json output. i made a cart that get json data from the controller using ajax, and i tried to parse the output. eventually i failed to get a result. its stated undefined.

here is my draft

```
loop hypermart json element { 

    loop productname element{
        get price based on productname + price
    }
}
```

so every mart will have the same product name and different price on each mart. how can i achieve this kind of output? im cornered by question that i yet to have the answer.

this is the json data

```
[{
    "productId":1002,
    "productName":"Moghul Faiza Basmathi",
    "productPic":"",
    "brandName":"Faiza",
    "productVolume":"5kg",
    "barcode":"9555035703811",
    "manufacturer":"Faiza",
    "createdBy":{
        "userId":2,
        "username":"pak.ijan",
        "password":"********",
        "fullName":"Hizan Ahmad",
        "sessionId":"********"},
        "dateCreated":"Jul 9, 2014 3:52:08 AM",
        "modifiedBy":{
            "userId":2,"username":"pak.ijan",
            "password":"********",
            "fullName":"Hizan Ahmad",
            "sessionId":"********"},
            "lastModified":"Jul 9, 2014 3:52:08 AM",
            "status":1,
    "price":[{
        "priceId":0,
        "hypermart":{
            "hypermartId":1,
            "hypermartName":"Tesco",
            "hypermartLogo":"",
            "status":1},
        "priceDate":"Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
        "productPrice":0.0,"status":1},
        {"priceId":1,
        "hypermart":{
            "hypermartId":2,
            "hypermartName":"Giant",
            "hypermartLogo":"",
            "status":1},
        "priceDate":"Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
        "productPrice":0.0,"status":1},
        {"priceId":2,
        "hypermart":{
            "hypermartId":3,
            "hypermartName":"Jusco",
            "hypermartLogo":"",
            "status":1},
        "priceDate":"Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
        "productPrice":0.0,
    "status":1}],
    "tag":"beras faiza basmathi moghul",
    "description":"Moghul Faiza Basmathi",
    "category":{
        "categoryId":7,
        "descEn":"Food",
        "descMy":"Makanan"}
}]
```

Comment: You could start iterating with `for`. Thoughts?

Comment: If you are capable enough to write JavaScript and hit a server via Ajax to get a response, you should realize that your jquery ajax call already parses the response and you have a plain old JavaScript object.  There is no JSON there anymore.  So pull your data from your **JavaScript** object.  Again, it is not JSON anymore.  Is your question how to navigate a JavaScript object?

Comment: By the way, what is "Moghul Faiza Basmathi" :-) ? Some sort of rice?

Answer (score 1):

Say you get a data string from your server, like

```
var myDataJson = [{
  "productId":1002,
  ...
  "price":[{
    "priceId":0,
    "hypermart":{
        "hypermartId":1,
        "hypermartName":
  ...
 }]
```

Now it is simple. You have to parse `myDataJson`. As a result, you immediately get a real JavaScript object. Remember, JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.

So one contemporary way to parse is:

```
try {
  var myCartData = JSON.parse(myDataJson);
} catch (ex) {
  ...
}
```

Now you can access your real Javascript object like every other Javascript object:

```
for (key in myCartData) {
   var product = myCartData[key];
   var price = product['price'][0]['productPrice'];
   ...
}
```

Possibly you should look for further methods to parse your JSON string as `JSON.parse()` is not supported by old browsers. Here are many ideas: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to loop out one by one element recursive. For that you should stat with learn from scratch and spend some time in it.

I am try to solve it for you.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [
    {
        "productId": 1002,
        "productName": "Moghul Faiza Basmathi",
        "productPic": "",
        "brandName": "Faiza",
        "productVolume": "5kg",
        "barcode": "9555035703811",
        "manufacturer": "Faiza",
        "createdBy": {
            "userId": 2,
            "username": "pak.ijan",
            "password": "********",
            "fullName": "Hizan Ahmad",
            "sessionId": "********"
        },
        "dateCreated": "Jul 9, 2014 3:52:08 AM",
        "modifiedBy": {
            "userId": 2,
            "username": "pak.ijan",
            "password": "********",
            "fullName": "Hizan Ahmad",
            "sessionId": "********"
        },
        "lastModified": "Jul 9, 2014 3:52:08 AM",
        "status": 1,
        "price": [
            {
                "priceId": 0,
                "hypermart": {
                    "hypermartId": 1,
                    "hypermartName": "Tesco",
                    "hypermartLogo": "",
                    "status": 1
                },
                "priceDate": "Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
                "productPrice": 100,
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "priceId": 1,
                "hypermart": {
                    "hypermartId": 2,
                    "hypermartName": "Giant",
                    "hypermartLogo": "",
                    "status": 1
                },
                "priceDate": "Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
                "productPrice": 250,
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "priceId": 2,
                "hypermart": {
                    "hypermartId": 3,
                    "hypermartName": "Jusco",
                    "hypermartLogo": "",
                    "status": 1
                },
                "priceDate": "Jul 13, 2014 12:17:46 PM",
                "productPrice": 370,
                "status": 1
            }
        ],
        "tag": "beras faiza basmathi moghul",
        "description": "Moghul Faiza Basmathi",
        "category": {
            "categoryId": 7,
            "descEn": "Food",
            "descMy": "Makanan"
        }
    }
];

$(document).ready(function(){   

    var martDict = getPriceByName("Moghul Faiza Basmathi")
    console.log(martDict);
    var martDetail = "martDetail";
    var hypermartName = "hypermartName";
    var martPrice = "martPrice";

    for(i in martDict){
        //console.log(martDict[i]);
        //console.log(martDict[i][martDetail]);
        //console.log(martDict[i][martDetail][hypermartName]);
        var martName = martDict[i][martDetail][hypermartName];
        var price = martDict[i][martPrice]
        console.log(martName+" -> "+price);
    }
});

function getPriceByName(name){
    var productName = "productName";
    var price = "price";
    var hypermart = "hypermart";
    var productPrice = "productPrice";
    var martDict = [];
    //console.log(name);
    for(i in data){
        if(data[i][productName] == name){
            //console.log(data[i][productName]);
            var priceList = data[i][price];
            //console.log(priceList);
            for(j in priceList){
                //console.log(priceList[j]);
                //console.log(priceList[j][hypermart])
                var martDetail = priceList[j][hypermart];
                var martPrice = priceList[j][productPrice];
                martDict.push({"martDetail":martDetail,"martPrice":martPrice});
            }
        }
    }

    return martDict;
}
</script>
```

Still if you are not getting your answer elaborate your problem.

I have put all console comment as it is so that you will get better idea by open comments one by one.

[image]